# Can torchtext's BucketIterator pad all batches to the same length?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, preprocessor, torchtext

I recently started using torchtext to replace my glue code and I'm running into an issue where I'd like to use an attention layer in my architecture. In order to do this, I need to know the maximum sequence length of my training data.

The problem is that `torchtext.data.BucketIterator` does padding on a per-batch basis:

```
# All 4 examples in the batch will be padded to maxlen in the batch
train_iter = torchtext.data.BucketIterator(dataset=train, batch_size=4)
```

Is there some way to ensure that *all training examples* are padded to the same length; i.e., the maxlen in training?

Comment: Related question: If you're using `BucketIterator` with `sort_within_batch=True` , do you still need to called `pack_padded_sequence`?

Comment: Yes. The batch will define the `max_length` within the batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When instantiating a `torchtext.data.Field`, there's an optional keyword argument called `fix_length` which, when set, defines the length to which all samples will be padded; by default it is not set which implies flexible padding.